# Saving a bunch of floats to a binary file

Tags: c, user-input, binaryfiles

I need to save up to 16 floats to a bin file, to be later read and some things done to the information, but I have a problem from the get go as I'm not too sure what the best method to do this is and what I've written doesn't work

```
void FileMaker (void)
{
char buff[10];
float num;
int count = 0;
printf("Enter 16 Floating numbers:");
FILE *fh = fopen ("Matrix.bin", "wb");

if (fh == NULL)
printf("Fail");

if (fh != NULL)
    {
        while (count >17)
        {
            fgets(buff, 10, stdin);
            num = atof(buff);
            fwrite(&num, sizeof(float), 1, fh);
            count++;
        }
    fclose (fh);
    }
}
```

Basically what I've tried to do is one at a time get a float from the keyboard and then print it to the file and repeat 16 times but the program does nothing instead and reaches the return (0) in main without getting anything from the user.

Comment: Probably `fh == NULL`. What happened to your code that does error checking?

Comment: Added a if statement for fh == NULL, it isn't entered, should have added that I was just lazy/forgetful also changed buff to buff[10] to remove a few warnings hasn't made a difference to how it runs though.

Comment: `if (fh == NULL) printf("Fail");` - you're actively trying to make life harder for yourself. Print out the actual error (with `perror`, or using `strerror`), otherwise you'll never know why the thing failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
while (count >17)
```

the code will not enter the block, because `0 > 17` is false.

try this:

```
while (count < 17)
```

(or I personally like more the `for` loops)

```
for (count = 0; count < 17; ++count)
{
...
}
```

Comment: however, this will ask for 17 numbers... (0th, 1st ... 16th) - if count is 16, you'll ask for another number...

Comment: Yeah I figured that out after running it once, thanks though, something so simple but would have probably taken me hours to figure out by myself.